# How to catch particular primary id of each user in table using post method in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-modal, crud

I am completely new to programming. Basically I am working on crud operations with PHP and MySQL.

Below is my code to retrieve data from the database. Please notice that I used
hidden input field to catch primary key (`id`) of each user.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="datatable-buttons"  class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
    <thead>
      <tr class="headings">                                  
        <th class="column-title">Client Name</th>
        <th class="column-title">PAN </th>    
        <th class="column-title">GST Registration Type </th>    
        <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr">Add</span>
        </th>                                  
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
      $sql = mysqli_query($conn,'select * from customer_master');
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
      {?>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="even pointer">                                    
          <td class=" "><?php echo $row['companyName'];?></td>
          <td class=" "><?php echo $row['pan'];?></td>    
          <td class=" "><?php echo $row['gstTaxType'];?></td>                   
          <td><input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $row['customerId'];?>"></a> | <a type="" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_customer_profile"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        </tr>                                                 
      </tbody>
    <?php  }?>                                
  </table>
</div>
```

When clicking `data-target="#edit_customer_profile"` second modal will
open data for the particular `customerId` only.

For this I used this query in second modal.

```
<?php $sql = mysqli_query($conn,'select * from  customer_master');
                                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {?>
```

So please help me to retrieve data of selected user's only.

Comment: 'select * from  customer_master where customerId = $_POST['customerId']' are your looking for something like this ?

Comment: right bro im looking for this only.

Comment: does it work ? @amit

Comment: Now see about parametrised queries

Comment: no bro its now working .gives error undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the WHERE-clause in your SELECT statement. Be sure to use the prepared-statements to avoid SQL-Injection.

Here a example from the [PHP-docs] (http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php) changed on your needs:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM  customer_master WHERE customerId=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['customerId']);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($customerId);
    $stmt->bind_result($companyName);
    $stmt->bind_result($pan);
    $stmt->bind_result($gstTaxType);

    /* fetch value */
    $stmt->fetch();

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="datatable-buttons"  class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headings">                                  
                <th class="column-title">Client Name</th>
                <th class="column-title">PAN </th>    
                <th class="column-title">GST Registration Type </th>    
                <th class="column-title no-link last"><span class="nobr">Add</span></th>                                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="even pointer">                                    
                <td class=" "><?php echo $companyName;?></td>
                <td class=" "><?php echo $pan;?></td>    
                <td class=" "><?php echo $gstTaxType;?></td>                   
                <td><input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $customerId;?>"></a> | <a type="" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_customer_profile"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
            </tr>                                                 
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```